# AS3 - Remove focus of StageText field

Tags: actionscript-3, air, textfield

I'm setting the focus to a [StageText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StageText.html) textfield with `stagetext.assignFocus()` (The cursor is blinking in there)

How can that focus be removed so the cursor is not blinking anymore?

(I'm using Flash CS 6 and Air 3.6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
stage.focus = null;
```